# Native look using css and js

Tags: mobile, cross-platform, frontend

I've been using one particular front-end framework for mobile apps for quite sometime but I won't mention the name here because it is irrelevant to my question. I've tried its other competitors, but none piqued my interest.

Particularly they all seems hard to customise with Bootstrap templates.
Bootstrap IS responsive and now mobile first, but it needs additional library to make it more native looks and feels.

So I think, may be I should try small libraries working together with Bootstrap.

I am looking into library/code that will make my web-based, Bootstrap apps feels and looks native to smartphone/tablet.

Here I list what I think are supposedly the right behaviours to have:

### 1. Fast click

This one I already know the library: [Fastclick](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick).

### 2. Hidden Scrollbar

Maybe this one is sufficient? [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5GCsJ/4713/):

**Javascript**

```
var parent = document.getElementById('container1');
var child = document.getElementById('container2');
child.style.paddingRight = child.offsetWidth - child.clientWidth + "px";
```

**CSS**

```
*{margin:0;}
#container1{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid green;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#container2{
    width: 100%;
    height: 99%;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-right: 0px; /* exact value is given in JavaScript code */
}

html, body{
    height: 99%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

### 3. Disabled Zooming

Is this sufficient?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no"/>
```

or should I use this?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

### 4. Ability to Include partial .html page (for fast loading, particularly a shared `<head>` tag):

```
Please suggest library or code
```

Please leave comment if you think I should add more behaviours. For now, these 4 behaviours are what I'm looking into.

FYI, I've tried OnsenUI with AdminLTE (Bootstrap Template), almost successful, but the scrollbar behaviour is bad. (showing when not supposedly shown, and the scrollbar looks is not that of native.